# Error when updating translated content

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have fought for some time with the error below:

> Non-translatable field elements can only be changed when updating the original language.

I have "inherited" a site a few years ago and been updating it so it's D8 up-to-date (8.9.16).

When the user tries to save a change in language version of a page (on many but not all pages), she gets the aforementioned error message (even if not changing anything on the form).

After researching the problem a bit I found out about the module: Remove Entity Untranslatable Field Validation. I installed it and it made its magic going through the pages but the problem just didn't go away after that.

Other than that there's not much help in the web and I am running out of options, does anyone here have any suggestions what to try next?

Comment: Perhaps going to "admin/config/regional/content-language" and checking "Hide non translatable fields on translation forms" option for your contents might help.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately all those are already checked. Should have (and thought to but forgot) mentioned that in the question

Comment: This is crucial for the question, but checking could cause the issue, not unchecking. Also important is the information which fields are configured non-translatable. Not all fields should be and there is still an open issue with multi-property widgets. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3026055

Comment: Ok, unchecking the boxes really solved the problem. I still feel that wording makes me think just the other way round, but who cares when  it works :) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

**Solution:**

- Goto /admin/config/regional/content-language
- then check CONFIGURATION "Hide non translatable fields on translation forms"
- if it's still
  happening then check TRANSLATABLE (* unsupported) fields.

Solved.

Answer (score 2):

This issue may be related to your problem.
https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_revisions/issues/3150084

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking all "Hide non translatable fields on translation forms"-boxes in Content language-configuration page solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by going to `/admin/config/regional/content-language` looking for the content type and enabling the translation for the `published` field. I think that the module workflow was trying to set a specific value for that field in the translated node and that caused the issue.